# JFreeChart - Problem in creating moving chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, time-series

I am using JFreeChart in my java application.

**Problem**

I want to plot a **XYAreaChart** whose **domain axis (x-axis)** should scroll horizontally automatically when we start plotting the data.

I saw the same thing in **TimeSeriesCharts** but I don't want any timeSeriesChart. I just want the scrolling x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create your own `SlidingXYDataset` that implements [XYDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html) in a manner similar to how [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/SlidingCategoryDataset.html) implements `CategoryDataset`.

Addendum: As noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367222/jfreechart-problem-in-creating-moving-chart/5381430?noredirect=1#comment6128816_5381430), a typical implementation can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/patches/231/).

Comment: I found one patch for it at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2439953&group_id=15494&atid=315494 but I have one problem in it when I want to set my own range of X-axis. This example works fine with plot.getDomainAxis().setAutoRange(true).. but I want to set my own range for x-axis.

Comment: It's a little dated, but it works. What's wrong with `setFirstItemIndex()`? IF you want a fixed domain range, see this [DynamicTimeSeriesCollection example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852).

Comment: Sorry, I did *not* want to downvote this answer. Is it possible to correct this?