# How can I add a horizontal scroll bar in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, netbeans-7

Can I include a horizontal scroll bar to view the previous data in a `JFreechart`?
I am using linechart graph to draw dynamic graph and showing 10 values on x-axis at a time, I want to view the graph with a horizontal scroll bar.

How can I set the values for scrollbar to view the previous data?

Answer (score 2):

Several options are available:

- Adding your `ChartPanel` to a `JScrollPane`,
- Using a [`SlidingXYDataset`](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2439953&group_id=15494&atid=315494), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381430/230513),
- Using a paging approach, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).
- Addendum: Using a `SlidingCategoryDataset` with `ChartFactory.createLineChart()`.

Comment: Hi @trashgod. Thanks for your quick reply. Sorry,i have edited my post. Actually i am using Linechart because i am having numeric values both on x-axis and y-axis. In case of timeseries i can get minimum value of domainaxis and then as per scrollbar value i can show records on graph area. But in this case of Linechart can you please suggest me how would i able to see my previous data?

Comment: Even easier: `SlidingCategoryDataset` is covered in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Comment: My x-axis values fall between -3 to 3. so how will i move backward to get previous values?

Comment: I never tried that. Which approach have you decided to pursue? Please edit your question to include the latest requirements and an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.