# JFreeChart using shifting one series by a given offset value

Tags: java, jfreechart

Let's assume that I have one instance of the org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset and that I am adding two series to it in this way:

```
dataset.addSeries(name, values);
dataset.addSeries(name2, values)
```

How can I move the first or the second series by the X or Y offset value?

> Assume that offset is always >= 0. By moving 'right' I mean each (x,y)
>   point transform to (x + offset, y) point.

Moving 'left', 'up' and 'down' by analogy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultXYDataset` is convenient for accessing individual elements of different series, but it doesn't expose the methods needed to manipulate the internal data structures in this way. Instead, implement the `XYDataset` interface by extending [`AbstractXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/AbstractXYDataset.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513), where you can encapsulate the offset plumbing. You may also want to look at `SlidingXYDataset`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381430/230513).

Comment: Could you provide any short snippet to show what do you mean by 'offset plumbing'. I would need a flexible solution to efficiently manipulate with quite large amount of data.

Comment: I can only guess at what _you_ mean by _offset_; a common use-case is suggested by the two datasets contrasted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513); if you have something else in mind, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Maybe `setDomainPannable(true)`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18421887/230513).

Comment: After some tests I recognized that keeping the reference to the value's array (double[][]) and modyfying the values inside (you can do whatever transformation you need) and afterwards calling chart.fireChartChanged() solves the problem. However I am not sure what about efficiency, but if JFreeChart doesn't provide API for transformations it seems be a good way.

Comment: As an implementation detail, no copies are made in `addSeries()`.