# ChangeListener on scrollbar using zoom in button

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm a beginner in JavaSwing and JFreeChart.
I have done an XYLineChart and I have add a scrollbar to this chart. I have done an SlidingXYDataset class like a SlidingCategoryDataset for my XYLineChart. And then my scrollbar works. This is the code:

```
JScrollBar scroller = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 10, 0, 20);

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    int value = scroller.getValue();
    dataset.setFirstItemIndex(value);
}
```

And now, I don't know how to adapt this scrollbar when I use the zoom. For my zoom, I have a button with an ActionListener. When I push the button, it triggers this code (in the constructor of my panel, the setMouseZoomable is false):

```
public class ZoomListener extends MouseAdapter{
    private SpectrumPanel specPanel;   
    private SpectrumController control;
    private ChartPanel panel;
    private JFreeChart chart;

    public ZoomListener(SpectrumController c){   
        control = c;
        specPanel = c.getSpectrumPanel();
        panel = c.getSpectrumChartPanel().getChartPanel();
        chart = c.getSpectrumChartPanel().getChartPanel().getChart();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
        panel.setMouseZoomable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        panel.removeMouseListener(this);
        panel.setMouseZoomable(false);
        panel.setHorizontalAxisTrace(false);
        panel.setVerticalAxisTrace(false);

        specPanel.getGraphPanel().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
}
```

If you have ideas to link my scrollbar to the zoom, I'll take it with pleasure. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't use a JScrollBar for this purpose, use a JSlider, it's what it's designed for

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381430/230513).

Comment: I tried with a JSlider but it's the same problem: when I zoom, the slide doesn't work. Do I link the JSlider to the zoom with a specific method?

Comment: you have to put the zoom code to the `statechanged` method in `addChangeListener` of `JSlider`. And if you want to refer someone use @personname to notify that person