# Split histogram - JfreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I built an histogram with Java using JFreeChart API, but I have an issue with large dataset. For example, this is the different between a large and a small dataset:
This is the histogram with a small dataset:
[image]

But when I have a very large dataset this is the result:
[image]

When I have a large dataset is there any way to split the histogram in smaller pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ChartFactory.createXYBarChart()`, here are some approaches:

- Zoom the chart by either dragging a selection or using the context menu,
- Add custom controls, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).
- Use a custom `SlidingXYDataset`; an example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381430/230513).
- Adopt a paging approach, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).